# Cuando me quito el calzado, ¿por qué estoy "descalzo" y no "descalzado"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología

El calzado es una *clase o conjunto de prendas que cubren o protegen el pie y tienen suela* ([RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6sj2UIn)). De ahí que cuando llevamos dichas piezas en los pies, digamos que estamos "calzados". Mi padre diría "Cálzate antes de salir de casa" y cosas así.

Sin embargo, cuando nos desprendemos de estas prendas pasamos a tener los pies *descalzos*. ¿Por qué no **descalzados**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Descalzo viene de *des + calceus*, y este último a su vez de *calx*, talón. *Calceus* significa "calzado" o "zapato", luego "descalzo" significa literalmente "sin zapatos":

> **descalzo, za**
>   Del part. irreg. de *descalzar.*
>   1. adj. Que no lleva calzado. *Niño, pie descalzo.*

Para describir a una persona sin zapatos se pueden usar tanto el participio regular (descalzado) como el irregular (descalzo). Existen muchos verbos con doble participio, y en algunos casos como este mismo el irregular, también llamado participio fuerte o trunco, ha perdido su productividad para formar tiempos compuestos y ha quedado relegado a adjetivo estativo, mientras que el regular aun puede asumir ambos roles. Según la [RAE](http://www.rae.es/consultas/dobles-participios-imprimidoimpreso-freidofrito-proveidoprovisto#sthash.vOG9bGer.dpuf):

> Algunas de estas formas [participios irregulares] pueden haber funcionado como participios verbales en épocas pasadas del idioma, pero hoy funcionan solamente como adjetivos y, por lo tanto, no se usan en la formación de los tiempos compuestos ni de la voz pasiva de los verbos correspondientes.

Otros ejemplos de este tipo son "someter", con "sometido" (part. + adj.) y "sumiso" (adj.); "regir", con "regido" (part. + adj.) y "recto" (adj.); o "atender", con "atendido" (part. + adj.) y "atento" (adj.).

Citando a [Rodríguez Espiñeira](https://books.google.es/books?id=z5aov9ozWx0C&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=adjetivo+fuerte+o+trunco&source=bl&ots=3eJ2s1UJ0p&sig=q4VaJ58KwosjNjwDHBnvpi65nJg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLkfyvkN_LAhWLWRQKHXkXDE8Q6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=adjetivo%20fuerte%20o%20trunco&f=false):

> Entre estos adjetivos, algunos como *adjunto, 
>   despierto, disperso, electo, enfermo, extinto, fijo, frito, impreso, inserto, preso, salvo, sujeto* han perdido las propiedades gramaticales y semánticas de su origen verbal, aunque denotan el estado resultante en el que desemboca la acción o proceso indicado por el verbo, como lo indica su compatibilidad con estar, con adverbios perfectivos [ya, una vez, recién] y su función de predicado de una oración absoluta (9a). Los mismos comportamientos (9b) presentan otros adjetivos, como ***descalzo***, desnudo, limpio, sucio, lleno, vacío, seco, cono, contento, absorto, estupefacto, harto, oculto, molesto, perplejo, exhausto. maduro, tenso, trunco, cuya relación con los participios, al menos del español, es menos clara (Varela 2005). Unos y otros pertenecen a la clase de los denominados "adjetivos perfectivos" (Bosque 1990).
>
> (9a) El libro está impreso en Amberes. Un libro recién impreso. Una vez impreso, el libro salió a la venta
>   (9b) El salón está lleno. Un salón totalmente lleno. Ya lleno el salón, comenzó el acto

Otra característica de estas formas es la variación en significado: en algunos casos ambas formas mantienen significados casi idénticos, como "soltado" y "suelto", y con otros se producen grandes variaciones, como "torcido" y "tuerto" o "convenido" y "convento". En el caso de "descalzo" y "descalzado" ambas formas mantuvieron su significado original. Por qué se hizo más popular una forma que la otra es difícil de saber. Podríamos preguntarnos lo mismo con todos los adjetivos citados más arriba<sup>1</sup>. Yo, como persona lega en la materia, no tengo una respuesta.

Ahora bien, este proceso de [regularización analógica de participios](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog%C3%ADa_(morfolog%C3%ADa)) no afectó a todos los participios por igual y no siempre produjo la pérdida total de la forma no regularizada. En el caso de "descalzo"<sup>2</sup>, ambas formas coexisten, y de hecho este último suele impedir el uso de "descalzado" como adjetivo, aunque no de forma absoluta. Algunos ejemplos en la literatura española extraídos del [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll) son:

> > ¿Quién, pues, no temerá un mundo tan peligroso? ¿Quién no procurará escaparse de tanto lazo? ¿Quién no temblará de andar como andan los malos, **descalzados** entre tantas serpientes, desarmados entre tantos enemigos, desproveídos entre tantas ocasiones, sin medicina entre tantas enfermedades mortales, y sin mástel y gobernalle en un golfo tan tempestuoso?
>
> Granada, F. L. (1559). *Manual de diversas oraciones y espirituales ejercicios (edición ampliada)*
>
> > Generalmente se usan para la aplicación muñecas de trapo (preferibles, al parecer, á los pinceles ó escobillas) que se fijan á un mango para preservar las manos y con ellas se embadurnan abundantemente el tronco de las cepas (podadas y **descalzadas** previamente) y los brazos, como también los vástagos y los sarmientos largos, sin respetar siquiera las tiernas yemas, cuidando sobre todo de que se impregnen bien las úlceras ó chancros, penetrando el líquido en su interior.
>
> Ascárate y Fernández, C. (1893). *Insectos y criptógamas que invaden los cultivos en España.*
>
> > Felipe comió y bebió. Pronto se halló restaurado. Una india buena, esposa del guardián que servía entonces a Felipe, trajo un barreño lleno de agua caliente, y allí metió el viajero sus pies, previamente **descalzados.**
>
> Ortega Munilla, J. (1921). *Los tres sorianitos.*
>
> > Los gallegos solían ser procedentes de las aldeas más miserables de la región: la mayoría estaban increíblemente sucios, pringosos; frecuentemente **descalzados.**
>
> Barea, A. (1951). *La forja de un rebelde.*

Como se puede ver, en el primer y cuarto caso "descalzados" se puede sustituir por "descalzos". En el segundo y tercero, en cambio, no. Ello es porque el uso del participio regular generalmente alude al resultado de una acción (la de descalzarse), función propia de los participios, mientras que el participio irregular generalmente expresa tan solo un estado (el de estar descalzo), función propia de los adjetivos. Un niño que jamás se ha puesto unos zapatos no se definiría probablemente como "descalzado", mientras que sí se puede usar la misma palabra para una persona que se acaba de descalzar. Al usar la palabra "previamente" en ambos ejemplos citados, se bloquea la interpretación del participio como un estado que dura en el presente, no así la del resultado de una acción. Al contrario, el uso de "previamente" normalmente indicaría que el estado ha cambiado cuando se usa un adjetivo:

> Marta, una chica previamente alegre, ya no salía de casa. (Marta ya no está alegre)

Pero no cuando se usa un participio que describe una acción:

> La carne, previamente cocinada, está lista para la mesa. (La carne sigue estando cocinada)

En el caso de "descalzados", si se hubiese usado el participio irregular "descalzos" una interpretación posible podría haber sido que las cepas o los pies ya no están descalzos. "Descalzos" puede ser tanto el estado como el resultado, por lo que la interpretación de que aun siguen descalzos puede darse, pero desde luego se estaría aumentando la ambigüedad del texto.

En conclusión, "descalzo" y "descalzado" son intercambiables hasta cierto punto. No está claro que el segundo haya surgido como una regularización del primero. Sea como sea, mientras que solo el segundo puede hacer de participio, como adjetivo, en cambio, [el primero es mucho más común](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=descalzo%2Cdescalzado&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=10&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdescalzo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdescalzado%3B%2Cc0). Existe entre ambos un matiz distinto, así como algunas diferencias sintácticas, pero son en gran medida sinónimos.

---

<sup>1: De hecho, en otras lenguas romances como el italiano esta coexistencia de formas regulares e irregulares es rara. En esta última lengua se conservaron las formas irregulares tanto para el adjetivo como para el participio, existiendo solo una forma para ambas: *retto* es tanto "regido" como "recto"; *sommesso* es tanto "sometido" como "sumiso", *pianto* es tanto "llorado" como "llanto", *nato* es tanto "nacido" como "nato", *risposta* es tanto "respondida" como "respuesta", *prodotto* es tanto "producido" como "producto", y lo mismo para otros muchos, muchos verbos.</sup>

<sup>2: Tal y como ya explicó Rodríguez Espiñeira, la relación entre "descalzo" y "descalzado" no está tan claramente ligada a los dobles participios como sí lo están otras formas como "despertado" y "despierto". Sin embargo, y ya que guardan la misma relación, siendo "descalzo" un adjetivo estativo tal y como lo es "despierto" y la mayoría de estas formas irregulares, aquí se tratan como tal.</sup>

Comment: Esta respuesta es fantástica, Yay. Me quito el sombrero ante tanta sabiduría combinada con la investigación tan exhaustiva. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 4):

Parece que antaño *descalzar* tenía un participio irregular: *descalzo* (así que habrían dicho *yo me he descalzo*). Hoy en día, obviamente, el participio es *descalzado*, pero como adjetivo *descalzo* se ha fijado en la lengua como ha acaecido con muchos otros participios antiguamente irregulares (*electo*/*elegido*, por ejemplo).

El hecho de que el participio *calzo* no tuvo el mismo resultado adjetival puede deberse a la existencia (o formación) del sustantivo *calzo*, aunque es pura especulación.