# Uso de "que" y "quien" cuando hablamos de la gente

Tags: gramática, pronombres

Pensaba, que la palabra `quien` es usada siempre cuando hablamos de la gente, mientras que la palabra `que` se refiere a otros objetos. Sin embargo, cuando escribo en el google la frase

> la gente que

recibo la recomendación:

> La gente que me gusta

Y cuando busco:

> La gente quien

Obtengo:

> La gente quien dice que soy yo

¿Alguien puede explicarmelo?

Ahora no sé si la forma correcta es

> La sociedad es llena de la gente quien / que piensa que (...)

Comment: El pronombre "que" se usa para objetos o personas en el 90% de los casos. Para personas, también se puede usar "quien", pero solo en situaciones muy formales, como pronombre interrogativo (quién) o cuando no hay antecedente expreso, en cuyo caso se puede usar "el/la que" o "quien". Cuando hay un antecedente, "quien" suena excesivamente formal, pero cuando no lo hay, suena más natural (por ej., "*quien* no quiera venir, que no venga" suena bien, pero "la persona *quien* no quiera venir, que no venga" no).

Comment: ¿Entonces debería usar "La sociedad es llena de la gente que piensa (...)", sí?

Comment: Mejor: "la sociedad **está** llena de gente que piensa (...)." *Lleno* funciona como un [participio trunco](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16296/cuando-me-quito-el-calzado-por-qu%C3%A9-estoy-descalzo-y-no-descalzado/16300#16300), y estos últimos suelen ir con *estar*. Algo "**es** *llenado*", pero "**está** *lleno*". Podría incluso decirse que "está llenado", pero lo que no se puede decir (o al menos ya no) es "es lleno".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Cláusulas especificativas vs explicativas

*Que* puede usarse tanto para objetos como para personas. El pronombre *quien* solo se puede usar para personas, y alterna básicamente con dos construcciones: *que* y *el/la que* (o *el/la cual*). En el primer caso, *que* es en la mayoría de los casos preferible, sobre todo en **cláusulas adjetivas especificativas**<sup>1</sup>:

> "Alberto es un chico **que** prometía mucho cuando iba a la Universidad, tenía talento."
>   Marsé, Juan (1966). *Últimas tardes con Teresa.*

En **cláusulas explicativas**, el pronombre *quien* es algo más común, aunque siempre es más seguro usar *que*:

> "La capa-paloma parecía que había dado alas al chico, **quien** se hizo más inquieto y diabólico desde que la poseyó."
>   Valera, Juan (1877). *El comendador Mendoza.*

En este último caso, el pronombre *quien* puede alternar con *el/la que*, o *el/la cual*:

> La capa-paloma parecía que había dado alas al chico, **el cual** se hizo más inquieto y diabólico.

Los relativos determinados (*quien, el/la cual, el/la que*) [no pueden ser sujeto de una oración especificativa](http://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vcodigo=12642), por lo que las siguientes frases son incorrectas:

> *Alberto es un chico **quien** prometía mucho cuando iba a la Universidad.
>   *Alberto es un chico **el que** prometía mucho cuando iba a la Universidad.
>   *Alberto es un chico **el cual** prometía mucho cuando iba a la Universidad.

Sí pueden ser sujeto de una oración explicativa, por lo que "La capa-paloma parecía que había dado alas al chico, **quien** se hizo más inquieto..." y "La capa-paloma parecía que había dado alas al chico, **el cual** se hizo más inquieto..." son correctas y naturales (nótese la coma después de "chico").

Los relativos no determinados (*que*), por el contrario, pueden ser sujeto de ambos tipos de cláusulas. Si se sustituyen las oraciones anteriores con el relativo *que*, estas siguen siendo correctas y naturales:

> La capa-paloma parecía que había dado alas al chico, **que** se hizo más inquieto y diabólico.

En resumen, "La sociedad está llena de gente quien..." no solo suena poco natural, sino que es incorrecto.

### Otros casos

1. Si no hay antecedente expreso

Una diferencia clave en el uso de *quien* es la presencia del antecedente. Todos los relativos tienen [por definición](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=yMHcHNHFgHjidmds) un antecedente, lo cual no significa que este deba aparecer de forma expresa. Cuando el antecedente no aparece explícitamente, se habla de "relativos con antecedente tácito". En estos casos, el relativo es su propio antecedente: son los relativos *quien, cuando, como* y *donde*:

> "Son [las mujeres] en sus antojos tan singulares, que no hay **quien** las entienda ni **quien** pueda seguirles el vuelo."
>   Mateo Luján de Saavedra (Juan Martí) (1602). *Segunda parte de la vida del pícaro Guzmán de Alfarache.*

En la frase anterior, *quien* hace tanto de antecedente como de relativo, sustituyendo a "persona que":

> Son las mujeres en sus antojos tan singulares, que no hay **persona que** las entienda ni **persona que** pueda seguirles el vuelo.

Cuando no hay antecedente expreso, no se puede usar *que*:

> *Son las mujeres en sus antojos tan singulares, que no hay **que** las entienda ni **que** pueda seguirles el vuelo.

2. En construcciones de relieve

Una construcción de relieve es una construcción predicativa <sup>2</sup> donde el segundo término es una cláusula relativa:

> Tú eres **el que** me debe dar una explicación.

Estas construcciones sirven para dar énfasis. Ya que no aparece un antecedente expreso, no se puede usar *que*:

> *Tú eres **que** me debe dar una explicación.

Las construcciones de relieve tienen la particularidad de que admiten los relativos *quien* y *el que*, pero no *el cual*:

> *Tú eres **el cual** me debe dar una explicación.

3. Con preposiciones

Las preposiciones pueden introducir construcciones relativas con o sin antecedente expreso. Sin embargo, no admiten el relativo *que* incluso cuando el antecedente aparece explícitamente. En este caso, se deberá usar *el/la que* o *el/la cual*:

> "Esto es lo que me han contao
>   y he oído generalmente,
>   a una voz, entre la gente
>   con **la cual** he platicao."
>   AAscasubi, Hilario (1872). *Aniceto el Gallo.*

Cuando no aparece antecedente expreso, se deberá usar *quien*:

> "Quizá en este momento le oprimen poderosos enemigos y se halla sin **quien** le defienda."
>   Milá y Fontanals (1844). *Compendio de arte poética.*

---

<sup>1: las cláusulas adjetivas especificativas especifican al antecedente de entre todos los de su clase, y se escriben sin comas. Las cláusulas adjetivas explicativas añaden información sobre un antecedente ya especificado, y se escriben entre comas.</sup>

<sup>2: las construcciones predictivas expresan alguna cualidad o propiedad del sujeto. El verbo típico en construcciones predictivas es "ser".</sup>

Comment: Qué honor tenerte aquí aportando respuestas tan magníficas.

Comment: @fedorqui Vaya, ¡gracias!