# ¿Cuál es el sujeto en la frase "Siempre creí que era el único que te podía hacer feliz"?

Tags: sintaxis

¿Cuál es el sujeto en la frase  "Siempre creí que era el único que te podía hacer feliz"?

Esta frase viene de otro idioma en donde está escrita más explícitamente de forma mas o menos así:

"Yo siempre creí que yo era el único quien te podía hacer feliz". Traducida en español así suena no natural y tal vez sintácticamente incorrecta en la parte en donde hay un "quien" en lugar de "que".

En el otro idioma la palabra que se considera algo parecido al sujeto es "el único", pero en español no es así, ¿o sí? ¿Cual sería el análisis sintáctico completo de la frase?

Comment: Yo "siempre creí que era el único que te podía hacer feliz”

Comment: La oración contiene tres proposiciones con tres sujetos. El sujeto de la primera es *yo*, el de la segunda puede ser o *yo* o *él/ella*, y el de la tercera es *que*, cuyo antecedente es *el único*. Aunque el sujeto de la segunda frase es ambiguo, la mayoría de los hablantes asumiría que el sujeto es *yo*. La frase que propones elimina la ambigüedad, pero suena poco natural. Para hacerla más clara, basta con añadir un solo *yo* delante de *era*.

Comment: Por cierto, *...el único **quien** te podía hacer feliz* es, efectivamente, incorrecto. Puedes leer más sobre *que vs quien* en esta pregunta: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17007/uso-de-que-y-quien-cuando-hablamos-de-la-gente/17008#17008

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El verbo es, sin duda, *creí*, por lo tanto estamos ante un caso de [sujeto omitido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sujeto_el%C3%ADptico), correspondiente al que habla ("***Yo***").

- *siempre* es un adverbio que actúa como complemento circunstancial.
- *que era el único* es parte del predicado. Concretamente, es una oración subordinada sustantiva que actúa como complemento directo de *creí* (cf. [DLE, *creer*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BDrUtPH), aceps. 1 y 3, y [DLE, *que*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UkbUarn), acep. 4).
- *que te podía hacer feliz* es una oración relativa en que la palabra *que* actúa como pronombre relativo para introducirla (cf. [DLE, *que*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UkbUarn), aceps. 1 y 2).