# Si tenemos "descalzo" y "descamisado", ¿cómo podemos nombrar a quien no lleva pantalón?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, adjetivos

El DLE recoge *descalzo* ([y no *descalzado*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16296/1674)):

> [**descalzo, za**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Cb8cYG2)
>   Del part. irreg. de descalzar.
>   1. adj. Que no lleva calzado. Niño, pie descalzo.

Y

> [**descamisado, da**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CbSVdFj)
>   1. adj. coloq. Sin camisa.

Sin embargo, no encuentro ninguna palabra para definir a aquel que va sin pantalones. ¿Existe? Se me ocurre *con el culo al aire*, pero no llevar pantalón no quiere decir no llevar ropa interior, por lo que no recoge todo el rango de significados.

Comment: Se me ocurre que puede no existir una palabra así porque, mientras que uno puede encontrarse en público con personas sin calzado o sin camisa, es más raro encontrarse con personas sin pantalones (sean cortos o largos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estaba pensando que tal vez sirva ***[desbragado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CZ3hn4U)***, que según el diccionario significa "sin bragas" y, despectivamente, "muy pobre".

Como en mi país no usamos la palabra *bragas*, no tengo claro si actualmente *desbragado* se refiere al que no lleva pantalones o, lo más probable, al que  anda "con el culo al aire", como dices tú, o sea, sin ropa interior. Pero revisando las definiciones de *bragas* y *desbragado* en el [Diccionario Castellano](https://books.google.cl/books?id=CzadZW_-E2oC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false) de Esteban de Terreros de 1786, podemos ver que antiguamente sí significaba lo que buscas.

Answer (score 4):

No he encontrado nada al respecto, salvo que **descalzo** y **descalzar** tenían anteriormente unos significados más amplios que actualmente. Así, el Diccionario de la lengua de 1732 recoge:

> **Descalzarse los guantes**: Vale lo mismo que quitarselos, desnudandose la mano de ellos"

y

> **Descalzo de pie y pierna**: El que no solo trae el pie desnudo y sin calzado, sino también la pierna sin media o calza.

por lo que parece que en esa época, **descalzo de pierna** equivaldría a "sin pantalones puestos".

Por otro lado, si no existe una palabra con ese significado, se podría crear. A primera vista parece que podría servir **desempantalonado**, formado a partir del prefijo
[**des-**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CJuPwUn)

> 1. pref. Denota negación o inversión del significado de la palabra simple a la que va antepuesto. *Desconfiar, deshacer.*
>   2. pref. Indica privación. *Desabejar.*

y del participio **empantalonado**, del verbo [**empantalonarse**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ElPpyvK):

> 1. prnl. Méx. Dicho de una mujer: Ponerse pantalones.

Esta propuesta tiene, sin embargo, varias pegas:

- La palabra es larga y es fácil pronunciarla o escribirla mal (como *desempantanolado*, por ejemplo)
- La palabra base, *empantalonarse* aparece marcada como de uso en **México**, y solo tiene la acepción de *ponerse pantalones* cuando está referida a **mujeres** [referida a hombres el significado es "presumir de hombría."]